# Error converting Swift 2 to Swift 3 on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode9

I downloaded Swift 2 file from Github and I am trying to work with in on my Xcode 9 with Swift 3 and I can't figure it out the last error I got left. It would be great if someone can help me out on where should I go to change this that would be helpful. Thank you.

```
The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. 
This setting can be set in the build settings editor.
```

Comment: Go look at the Swift Language Version in your build settings. What is it set to?

Comment: Add this to your Podfile

    `post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
       end
    end`